# Почему результат push и concat отображается по-разному?

Tags: angular2

Помогите пожалуйста понять почему при добавлении значений в массив разными способами, в шаблоне массив отображается по-разному. Живой пример [тут](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cncxkk).

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку add, отображаются обновления только в list2, list3. А при нажатии на кнопку add2, отображаются обновления в list1, list2, list3

```
list1: {{ heroes }}
<br>
list2: {{ heroes | json }}
<br>
list3:
<span *ngFor="let h of heroes">{{ h }}, </span>

<hr>
<button (click)="add()">add</button>
<button (click)="add2()">add2</button>


heroes: string[] = ['qwe', 'rty'];

  add() {
    this.heroes.push('new');
  }

  add2() {
    this.heroes = this.heroes.concat('new');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что `concat` создает **новый** массив. 
А `push` меняет содержимое существующего массива.

Подробнее:

- `concat` создает **новый** массив. Это значит, что теперь переменная `heroes` ссылается на новый массив.
- `push` меняет существующий. Это значит, что переменная `heroes` ссылается на старый массив, в котором есть новый элемент.

Проверить можно вот так:

```js
var arrayPush = [1, 2, 3];

var oldPush = arrayPush; // сохраняем ссылку

arrayPush.push(4); // изменяем существующий массив

console.log('новый и старый', arrayPush.length, oldPush.length);
console.log(oldPush === arrayPush); // будет true, потому что ссылка на массив не изменилась.

var arrayConcat = [1, 2, 3];
var oldConcat = arrayConcat; // сохраняем ссылку

arrayConcat = arrayConcat.concat([4]); // по сути, создаем новый массив

console.log('новый и старый', arrayConcat.length, oldConcat.length);
console.log(oldConcat === arrayConcat); // будет false, потому что ссылка на массив не изменилась.
```

Теперь *Angular*.

Почему различное поведение?
У вас имеется три случая:

1. `{{ heroes }}` - Такой тип записи отслеживает *только изменение по ссылке*
2. `{{ heroes | json }}` - Pipe **json** работает в режиме *отслеживать все изменения*. Другие pipe могут работать по другому.
3. `*ngFor="let h of heroes"` - данная директива `*ngFor` тоже работает в режиме *отслеживать все изменения*.

Соответственно, когда вы меняете значение массива через `push`, `{{ heroes }}` не видит изменения.